# Why won't my squads patrol my patrol route?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I've just set up my first patrol route but I'm having trouble getting my dwarves to patrol it. It is a simple two waypoint route across the top of my realm but squads assigned to patrol it just go to the second waypoint and stand there. Do I need to do something special to get them to walk back and forth? What else could be wrong?

Comment: This his very hard to tell from here. The military screen is complex, there are many things that could go wrong i guess! I don't know if this is a standard thing to go wrong because I have never tried patrolling, but since no-one else is answering I suggest you give more detail about what settings you used to set up the route...

Answer (score 2):

You likely haven't set them to the "Patrol route (X)" alert.

After creating the route you need to make sure they are on the patrolling schedule in the miltary scheduler.